Why does QDiskInfo report a "Caution" status on a relatively new disk?
I had a crash on Linux (due to bad block bitmap checksum) and after that I made some tests:

with a live Linux system I did a read only badblocks test, it read the full disk with no problems, although it showed a slow speed sometimes (from the normal ~120MB/s to ~40MB/s or so at times)
installed QDiskInfo and got the result in the image: 7900 hours is less than one full year of continuous usage, and it shows only 36 Reallocated Sector Count, but it still says "Caution"

Should I replace the disk?

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments, the number of reallocated sectors is 136. Interestingly, this grows steadily by 8 sectors every week or so (144, 152, 160, 168 and now 176). Really weird.

This is quite unreadable photo, but it still says enough to judge. Next time, do a proper screenshot instead of photographing the screen, for example, by hitting "PrintScreen" button on your keyboard (it can be Fn+PrtSc or something like that on the laptop), or run a proper screenshotting software, like Spectacle. SMART data also can be extracted as text. Just run sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda and copy-paste the terminal output; no need to even screenshot anything. That would be the best.
This disk isn't nearly "relatively new". Manufacturing defects typically show up in three months (manifesting as "infant death" sometimes), and that would be reasonable to consider "new". I wouldn't consider "new" a disk that was running for a year.
Nevertheless, without any reference to how old this disk is, it shows clear symptoms of imminent death. It has 136 sectors already reallocated (hex 88, if I am correctly reading the raw value on this bad photo). The value 36 that you see is in the threshold column, and that means, the disk itself is programmed to think it is dying once it was reached, but as you see, that is now far exceeded. Also, your badblocks test shows that it has unstable regions. So, like it or not, this disk is not reliable.
Back up all the valuable data as soon as you can; don't use the disk at all until you've done that, or you can lose your data. That means, shutdown the computer now and go to the parts shop!
Once you've replaced the faulty hardware, you may proceed with investigating the software crash. Don't try to do it in the reverse order, hardware problems need to be resolved first!

I believe the story with the threshold is different. SMART parameters work (or are supposed to work) this way: the firmware of the disk itself takes the raw value and calculates the current value in its own way. 100 or above is "all OK". The closer to 0, the worse, but if above the threshold then usually "still OK". See "Power On Hours" or "Seek Error Rate"; in both cases the raw value is way above the threshold, but this doesn't matter, what matters is the current value above the threshold. The disk itself considers "Reallocated Sector Ct" of 0x88 as totally fine (100=OK). Some think (cont'd)

(cont'd) Some think that any non-zero number of reallocated sectors is a sign the disk is dying. The program probably "thinks" this way, hence the caution. I'm not arguing with this. I'm just pointing out that most likely the threshold, the raw value and the worst value of "Reallocated Sector Count" belong to the same "normalized number line", while the raw value is in a totally different "space" and shall not be compared to them. ("Most likely" because AFAIK there is no firm specification followed by each and every manufacturer, so there may be exceptions in general.)

I would say that a non-zero number by itself it not that dangerous, and I even initially wanted to write to the answer that we better observe it in time, e.g. have smartd running and monitor logs. Still, we have a) observation from what appears to be a (almost) whole disk read, and that shows it has problems, and b) filesystem problems. That, with relocations, indicates disk already lost some data, but problems were only noticed when a bad block appeared where verifiable metadata lived. So it's just a sheer luck that it was noticed this early. And, with data, better safe than sorry.

I agree that suggested interpretation of 36 might be incorrect, it might be a percentage of the reserved area left and as we don't know how big is that area, we don't know how far we are. But again, experience shows that raw number grows, and 136 is too much for a year-old disk anyway, so it grows quickly, and it will use the reserves in a blink of an eye.

I'm not talking about data in general nor about the data, nor about the disk. My point is: comparing raw value to the threshold is wrong. Your conclusions may be right, but the statement that says "that is now far exceeded" is wrong. The disk itself is programmed to think it is dying once the threshold has been reached, but it's not the raw value that reaches the threshold from below, it's the current value that reaches the threshold from above on its way from 100 to 0 as the disk degrades.
